# Вопрос по Unix и установке сервера на него

Tags: unix, веб-сервер

Привет ребята, я новичок. Учусь системному администрированию. Поставил себе вчера unix на него хочу поставить сервер, apache. Собственно вопрос, правильно ли я начал свое обучение, или нужно было сразу покупать хостинг и уже там тренироваться?

Comment: правильно, так и нужно делать

Comment: Наберусь наглости заявить, что apache вроде как немножко устаревший и неэффективный и в 2016 году в большинстве случаев вместо него вполне катит nginx + FastCGI/uwsgi/что-нибудь-ещё

Comment: @andreymal, я пока токо учусь, для начала освою apache ну а потом уже по ходу nginx

Answer (score 1):

да, правильно начали обучение.

с точки зрения обучения абсолютно безразлично, где находится администрируемый компьютер — на столе, под столом, в соседней комнате, или в центре обработки данных.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, теперь хоть уверен что иду в правильном направление.

Comment: @Анатолий главное, работайте через командную строку, а не графические утилиты. В большинстве случаев администрируемый компьютер будет вам доступен только так.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, спасибо понял, так и делаю. Хотя очень сложновато.